# iOS SpriteKit - creating multiple "floors"

Tags: ios, xcode5, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a game for iOS using XCode 5 which replicates this game www.xgenstudios.com/play/castle

Basically, you press on the enemy and throw him into the air, and upon hitting the ground, he dies. But the enemy can spawn at an array of different y values so the "floor" they hit, and die from, is different depending on where they were spawned.

I'm new to spritekit development but from what I understand, the best way to program this would be:
-Create each stickman as a custom stickman node
-Create the background as a scene
-Create an invisible physics body object to act as boundary for which if they fall onto it they die

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could implement this? If the invisible boundary they hit is one place, they will always die in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to not use collision detection to solve this problem.  You could instead check if any StickManNodes that where in a thrown state had passed their original position during didSimulatePhysics.  You might then set the Y position exactly to the startY position and trigger your death animation.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but could be helpful in implementing it.  I would recommend you look into this it would allow you attach throw components to your nodes any time one is thrown.  The bonus is all the logic is encapsulated inside one class instead of inside your scene class. https://github.com/buddingmonkey/SpriteKit-Components